# Working of an eductor

Tags: fluid-mechanics, chemical-engineering, process-engineering

Am currently learning P&ID diagrams. I came across the term ‘eductor’ and I’m trying to understand its working. Apparently, it’s different from an ejector in the sense that it draws the fluid in. However when I look at the diagram, it seems that the fluid is being pushed out rather than in. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Eductors use liquid, as Ejectors use gas.  They are otherwise identical in function.

Ejectors tend to be used in steam condensers to draw vacuum and get rid of air, eductors are used as pumps.